# Shopify: Cannot overwrite generated asset

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

When running Shopify theme serve command on Shopify CLI, I see the message below.

```
12:27:56 ERROR  » update assets/filter-menu.css:
  Cannot overwrite generated asset 'assets/filter-menu.css'.
```

I tried adding this in .gitignore and config.yml fiels to see if it makes difference. But it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, for some reason I had a `product.js.liquid` file and shopify is now auto generating a `product.js` file.  The solution is to delete the `product.js.liquid` version and just work in the `.js` file.  If you are using the shopify cli then you may need to run theme pull again or delete the `.js.liquid` files and then push that up to shopify with the cli.